# How to grab a b2Body and move it around the screen? (cocos2d,box2d,iphone)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I want to move any b2body that is touched on the screen around the screen. I've heard something about mouse joints..

I found that: http://iphonedev.net/2009/08/05/how-to-grab-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-and-box2d/

but I just gives me a lot of errors if i just copy the ccTouch Methods into a new project (of course the variables in the header too). E.g. world->Query  <- NO MEMBER FOUND

May someone make a tut/a new project and upload it here. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have to create b2QueryCallback subclass:

```
class QueryCallback : public b2QueryCallback
{
public:
    QueryCallback(const b2Vec2& point)
    {
        m_point = point;
        m_object = nil;
    }

    bool ReportFixture(b2Fixture* fixture)
    {
        if (fixture->IsSensor()) return true; //ignore sensors

        bool inside = fixture->TestPoint(m_point);
        if (inside)
        {
             // We are done, terminate the query.
             m_object = fixture->GetBody();
                 return false;
        }

        // Continue the query.
        return true;
    }

    b2Vec2  m_point;
    b2Body* m_object;
};
```

Then in your touchBegan method:

```
    b2Vec2 pos = yourTouchPos;
// Make a small box.
b2AABB aabb;
b2Vec2 d;
d.Set(0.001f, 0.001f);
aabb.lowerBound = pos - d;
aabb.upperBound = pos + d;

// Query the world for overlapping shapes.
QueryCallback callback(pos);
world_->QueryAABB(&callback, aabb);         

b2Body *body = callback.m_object;
if (body)
    {
        //pick the body
    }
```

There are two ways I see you can control the picked body. The first one, as you notices - to create a mouseJoint and the second is to make your body kinematic and control it's velocity (not position! - it will provide non-physical behavior when collide because the speed will be zero). In first case if you will move your objects very fast there will be some delay when moving. I did not try the second way myself because in this case the body will not collide with other kinematic and static bodies.

Also you may want to lock body's rotation when moving.

Comment: +1 will try this out later, because i don't have a mac right now

Comment: @cocos: b2World is holding all the bodies pointers. So you can iterate over them and make their type kinematic. In box2d manual paragraph 6.2 is said static bodies never collide but nothing is said about kinematic. Actually i don't know but i suppose they can't because the physical behavior is undefined. But you can design your own class which will bind a dynamic body (actually a sensor) to your kinematic (with the same shape) and test if this bodies are colliding. Not sure it's a best way

Comment: @cocos: I can't. It's just an idea. I've never tried it myself. I would try to set a body's velocity like vel = cft*diff(fingerPos, bodyPos)

Comment: @cocos: mouseJoint (or any other) will not work with kinematic or static bodies because it's using forces when solving. But forces can't be applied to non-dynamic bodies

Comment: so i'm trying this: http://pastie.org/1663732  but the problem is that there's no really gravity after i move a body..

Comment: @cocos: you have to make your body dynamic after releasing it from touch. Gravity is a force and it's also applied only to dynamic bodies

Comment: @Andrew Only one problem is there (after that all will work fine(i hope): As you know from the code on pastie.org i'm using set transform to move the bodies. That means every time if i touch a body (let's say at the lower left of the body) the anchorpoint of it instantly goes to my touch. hm.. not great. Are you so kind and could change the code so that it works better. (you said something with velocity..setlinearvelocity??). Thanks! And at last: You're a genius thanks for you help to figure out how to move the body (kinematic....). THANKS! :)

Comment: @cocos: If you will move the body using setTransform for box2d it's velocity will still be zero. And the other bodies colliding with it will bounce incorrect (like from a static body (with zero velocity)). If you will control velocity instead of position physics will work fine. About the anchor point - the only way is to keep your first touch finger point relative to the body and use when controlling. anchorPoint = fingerPosition - bodyPosition. Then when your touch moves update it pos: anchoredTouch = touch + anchorPoint

Comment: May you show me the code? How to do that with the touch finger relative to the body?? Sorry I know what you think "What a stupid guy!?"...I'm a beginner..

Comment: @Andrew http://pastie.org/1663923    it's weired....if i move the finger :/ Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: @cocos: you are evaluating anchorPoint again in your touchMoves code. You should not. You have to evaluate it once when you touch the body (it's a point on a body what was touched). You have to do something like this: newLocation = location + anchorPoint (or minus possibly - try)

Comment: OK...i found a typo also.. now it works great!! Thanks Andrew!I'm so glad